# Why is this code throwing IllegalStateMonitorException

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads, thread-synchronization

I am trying to create a Blocking Queue using notifyAll() and wait() methods with a shared object. But this code throws IllegalMonitorStateException. Where do I need to make the change?

```
public class BlockingQueueNotifyAll<E> {

    private Queue<E> queue;
    private int max;
    private Object sharedQ = new Object();

    public BlockingQueueNotifyAll(int size) {
        queue = new LinkedList<>();
        this.max = size;
    }

    public synchronized void put(E e) {
        while(queue.size() == max) {
            try {
                sharedQ.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        queue.add(e);
        sharedQ.notifyAll();
    }


    public synchronized E take() throws InterruptedException {

        while(queue.size() == 0) {
            sharedQ.wait();
        }
        E item = queue.remove();
        sharedQ.notifyAll();
        return item;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you call `notifyAll` and `wait` on `sharedQ` but you are not doing it while holding the lock on `sharedQ` object. `synchronized` on your methods will make sure you acquire lock on `BlockingQueueNotifyAll` object.

From [`Object::wait`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--) docs :

> The current thread must own this object's monitor.

```
synchronized (obj) {  // here you acquire lock on obj
         while (<condition does not hold>)
             obj.wait();  // here you call wait on obj while holding the lock on this object
         ... // Perform action appropriate to condition
}
```

So in your case you call `wait` and `notifyAll` on object while not holding the lock on this object.

Answer (score 0):

So this code works-

```
public class BlockingQueueNotifyAll<E> {

    private Queue<E> queue;
    private int max;
    private Object sharedQ = new Object();

    public BlockingQueueNotifyAll(int size) {
        queue = new LinkedList<>();
        this.max = size;

    }

    public void put(E e) {

        synchronized (sharedQ) {
            while (queue.size() == max) {

                try {
                    sharedQ.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            queue.add(e);
            sharedQ.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public E take() throws InterruptedException {

        synchronized (sharedQ) {
            while (queue.size() == 0) { // replace if with an while

                sharedQ.wait();
            }
            E item = queue.remove();
            sharedQ.notifyAll();
            return item;

        }
    }

 }
```